# Output a NULL cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return empty cell from formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel)

I have an IF statement. If a cell = n, then do something, else output NULL

```
=IF(A1=5, "Success", NULL)   // #NAME?
=IF(A1=5, "Success", "NULL") // NULL (as in text, not actually NULL!)
=IF(A1=5, "Success", "")     // blank but not NULL
=IF(A1=5, "Success", 0)      // zero value but not NULL
```

Comment: could be good to add a link to the duplicated question while closing it..

Comment: Here is a way to return true empty blank as a formula result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351425/1903793

Comment: For people like me who had the same question: I return the #NULL! Excel error value that way `=SUM(A1 A2)`, with a space between the `A1` and the `A2`, assuming that both `A1` and `A2` are empty. Very convoluted but it seems to work (both ISERROR and ISERR return TRUE and ISTEXT return FALSE).

Answer (score 18):

As you've indicated, you can't output NULL in an excel formula. I think this has to do with the fact that the formula itself causes the cell to not be able to be NULL. "" is the next best thing, but sometimes it's useful to use 0.

--EDIT--

Based on your comment, you might want to check out this link. http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/mind-the-gap-charting-empty-cells/

It goes in depth on the graphing issues and what the various values represent, and how to manipulate their output on a chart.

I'm not familiar with VSTO I'm afraid. So I won't be much help there. But if you are really placing formulas in the cell, then there really is no way. ISBLANK() only tests to see if a cell is blank or not, it doesn't have a way to make it blank. It's possible to write code in VBA (and VSTO I imagine) that would run on a worksheet_change event and update the various values instead of using formulas. But that would be cumbersome and performance would take a hit.

Comment: I'm generating a graph from the data and so "" is graphed as 0 yet a NULL cell isn't graphed. Is there an equivalent or way of using ISBLANK()

Comment: @PeterCraig You can return NA() which won't be graphed.

Comment: YES! `NA()` will upload until SQL Server via SSIS as a NULL!

Answer (score 13):

I've been frustrated by this problem as well. Find/Replace can be helpful though, because if you don't put anything in the "replace" field it will replace with an -actual- NULL. So the steps would be something along the lines of:

1: Place some unique string in your formula in place of the NULL output (i like to use a password-like string)

2: Run your formula

3: Open Find/Replace, and fill in the unique string as the search value. Leave "replace with" blank

4: Replace All

Obviously, this has limitations. It only works when the context allows you to do a find/replace, so for more dynamic formulas this won't help much. But, I figured I'd put it up here anyway.