# Multiple IF formula is throwing an error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate a number of potential outputs in Excel, which I had working - but then I wanted to add a NULL output if the cell contained `0`.

Currently, I'm trying to provide the following output for one cell, based on data in a cell to the left:

```
If the figure is lower than 3% it'll spit out "Low"
If it's between 3 & 5%, it'll say "Medium"
And if it's more than 5%, it'll say "High"
```

I've managed to get the following to work:

```
=IF(C18>5%,"High",IF(C18<3%,"Low",IF(AND(C18>=3%,C18<=5%),"Medium")))
```

But now I want to add in a null volume for if the box doesn't contain a value. I tried:

```
=IF(C18>5%,"High",IF(C18<3%,"Low",IF(AND(C18>=3%,C18<=5%),"Medium",IF(C14=0,"Null"))))
```

but it won't work, and I'm stumped to what I can do to fix it. I had added in another "IF(AND" for "Low", but that threw things off completely.

Comment: I think you need to reorder the IFs - check for NULL first, then check for high, then check for low, and if all those fail then it's medium.

Comment: Your IFs are inside out.

Comment: Don't use "Null". Doing so will result in looking for a string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rearranging the order of your tests.  This will give you the results you're looking for:

```
=IF(C14=0,"Null",IF(C18>5%,"High",IF(C18<3%,"Low","Mediunm")))
```

First check to see if C14 is 0, as that will evaluate to NULL.  If it isn't 0, then check to see if C18 is greater than 5%, which results in High.  If it's less than 5%, check to see if it's less than 3%, which will result in Low.  Finally, return Medium (since C14 wasn't equal to 0 and C18 is greater than or equal to 3% and less than or equal to 5%.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much for the help Tim - worked a treat! Thanks also for the explanation, it's good to know that the logic behind it all as well, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(C18=0,"",IF(C18<0.03,"Low",IF(C18<0.05,"Medium","High")))
```

but adjust the break points to suit.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the last `IF`. I believe you meant `C18` not `C14`.

Anyway, that last `IF` will never execute because if C18 = 0, it `<3%` so it will be assigned `Low`. The formula is a lot easier to write (and read) if you follow the progression laid out in your business logic

```
=IF(C18=0,"Null",IF(C18<3%,"Low",IF(C18<=5%,"Medium","High")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel won't return NULL as a value.  See the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2558511/755908)

However, you could write it up so it displays N/A.

```
=IF(C18=0,NA(),IF(C18>5%,"High",IF(C18<3%,"Low",IF(AND(C18>=3%,C18<=5%),"Medium"))))
```