# Return Null, not "", as a condition of an IF statement in Excel

Tags: null, powerbi

I have a formula where I am comparing the number of days between two dates, however not all rows have one of the dates in which event Excel tries to calculate the difference between 01/01/1900 and the date e.g. a negative 41xxx number.

I want my formula to leave the cell blank when this happens and since my column type is whole numbers using "" will not work for me. Using 0 will not work either as it will affect my data as there will be some legitimate rows where 0 is the correct result.

How can I return a NULL so these rows are simply left empty?

Example formula below:

```
=IF([dateColA] = "", NULL, [dateColB]-[dateColA])
```

A small note, I am actually using Power BI Desktop however the engine accepts virtually all of Excel's formulas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output a NULL cell value in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558216/output-a-null-cell-value-in-excel)

Comment: What do you want to do with the data finally? Can you allow error values? In such a case you could return a function NA() for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the linked question and its "official [parent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel)" are good reading material for Excel use-cases, a better answer for PowerBI is the `BLANK()` function (in `DAX`), and its cousin `ISBLANK()`.  Reference [forum](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/IF-function-when-Date-is-empty/td-p/132191), [blog post](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/blank-handling-in-dax/), and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634820.aspx) (apparently the content hasn't been moved to `docs` yet).

So your formula would likely look something like this:

```
IF(ISBLANK([dateColA]), BLANK(), [dateColB]-[dateColA])
```

If this helps and is better suited for your case, you should probably edit the question and change the tag to `powerbi`. =)