# Excel VBA: Answer gets "stuck"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA in Excel 2003.  I've written a UDF that takes in two strings: one filter and one that will be a cell reference.  When I am debugging and call the function a couple times in a row in the VBA editor, everything works as I expect.  But when I use the UDF multiple times in a spreadsheet, all uses show the exact same answer, despite there being different input.

The function is below.  It updates a pivot table and then copies the value out of a cell.  But I must be misusing it:

```
Function UpdatePivotAndFetchCell(catcode As String, theCell As String) As Variant
Dim ws, pt, catField, pi, theval, finalVal
Set ws = Worksheets("Reporting")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("MyReport")
pt.RefreshTable
Set catField = pt.PivotFields("Category")

For Each pi In catField.PivotItems
    If InStr(pi.Value, catcode) Then
        pt.PivotFields("Category").CurrentPage = pi.Value
        theval = ws.Range(theCell).Value
        On Error Resume Next
        If (TypeName(theval) <> "Error") Then
            finalVal = theval
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
Next pi
UpdatePivotAndFetchCell = finalVal
End Function
```

If I run it with the VBA editor, I get:

```
Debug.Print (UpdatePivotAndFetchCell("C001", "K284"))
    'Returns 0.48
Debug.Print (UpdatePivotAndFetchCell("C002", "K284"))
    'Returns 0.52
```

But within a worksheet:

```
=UpdatePivotAndFetchCell("C001", "K284")
    (displays 0.52)
=UpdatePivotAndFetchCell("C002", "K284")
    (displays 0.52)
```

Am I not specifying the function properly, maybe?  It's a mystery to me.

Comment: can you post an example spreadsheet? Maybe as a public doc on dropbox? 

Also, have you tried setting a breakpoint in the function and stepping through the code?

Comment: Did you check the restrictions for writing UDFs? I remember that you cannot alter anything but the current cell, or the results are erratic. see http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/Functions.htm

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please realize that if you DIM a variable but don't set a type, then VBA defaults it to a variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions called from a worksheet are [not allowed to change sheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel). Otherwise you could easily create infinite loops in the calculation tree. So everything that changes the sheet is ignored (such as `RefreshTable()` or `.CurrentPage =`) and causes the function to stop.

For completeness sake, there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23433096/11683), but you **should not** use it, and you may [run into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698777/excel-office-365-restarts-automatically-while-executing-udf#comment92324771_52698777) if you do.

Comment: Ah ha.  What would you suggest as an alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, maybe I could make the thing that does the changing a sub, and have the result put out to some cell and grab it from there?  I'll go try.