# Use ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value in a Module to set/change the Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. Why can't I use following line in a module? But the same line seems to work fine in a sub

```vb
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "test"
```

[image: Excel Sheet]

```vb
Function trimto25(ByVal r As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim erg As Variant
    
    arr = Split(r, " ")
    erg = arr(0)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If (Len(erg + " " + arr(i)) < 25) Then erg = erg + " " + arr(i) Else: 
    Exit For
    Next i
    
    trimto25 = erg
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "test"    
End Function
```

ERROR-CODE in Excel Sheet: `#Value!`

This seems to work fine: (But why does it work in the sub and not the function)

```vb
Sub s()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "test"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the critics, i edited my question again ! i hope this is now more conform

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA: Answer gets “stuck”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3622137/11683)

Comment: Yes, thanks. That link is from Microsoft and explains the limitations of functions in generell and helped me too:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. User defined functions cannot change the state of the workbook/worksheet, cell, ecc. Use subroutine instead.

Comment: I am so sorry for the missunderstanding , i use it in an modul not in the cell

Comment: i edited my question now for better understanding :)

Comment: "But why does it work in the sub and not the function?": because in excel you can't change the e state of the workbook/worksheet, cell with a function only with a subroutine/macro. The software simply does not allow you to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much, you recognized the problem in the first moment !!

Answer (score 0):

The Offset command is VBA code rather than a formula.  It needs to be part of a Macro/module/code to actually do anything.

Comment: I am so sorry, i use it in an modul