# Make a custom function return nothing - not 0, not a blank string, but nothing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, user-defined-functions

I have a custom function to be called from inside a spreadsheets' cell, that I want to return nothing in some cases. In other words, I want the cell with my function to be treated exactly like an empty cell (unless the function returns a value).

The closest I can get to doing that is returning an empty string `""`. Unfortunately a cell with a zero length string is not treated as empty by `COUNTA` or `COUNTBLANK`, and breaks mathematical formulas (eg `1 + "" = #VALUE`).

Most of my attempts to return nothing cause a 0 to be returned, but this would be interpreted quite differently by the user.

What should I do?

Tried so far:

```
Returns 0:
    result = null
    result = VbEmpty
    result = Range("SomeCellKnownToBeEmpty")

Returns error:
    result = Nothing
```

Answer: I'm now reasonably sure that this is not possible, and the best that can be done is to work around it.

Work around options:

- Return a string `"-blank-"` and have a VBA macro delete the contents of any cell with `"-blank-"`. A strange approach, but fits my needs. I'm doing this as one of the steps in preparing my workbook for publishing.
- Return empty string and explicitly get other formulas in the sheet to treat `""` as blank.
- Return and display 0: Return 0 and use custom formatting to hide 0.

Comment: For functions like countblank it wouldn't matter what the function returned-the mere presence of a formula means the cell isn't blank. I'm afraid excel won't allow what you want-note that if you use =a1 where a1 is empty you return 0

Comment: Despite what others say, you may get a true blank as a formula result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351425/1903793

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble you have is that a UDF will *always* provide a value, so as such if you have a cell with a formula in it, it cannot be blank or empty which is what you want.

I think you might need to try and handle the zero or empty strings in your other formulas or convert the bigger process to entirely VBA.

For more reading see: http://excel.tips.net/T002814_Returning_a_Blank_Value.html

Edit: Possible duplicate: [Return empty cell from formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119614/1733206)

Answer (score 2):

Not for COUNT… functions, but to have Excel "lift up the pen" for charts/graphs/plots have the UDF return CVErr(xlErrNull).

This is rather bizarre since a *cell formula* that returns *NA()* will cause Excel to "lift up the pen"; but a UDF that returns CVErr(xlErrNA), does NOT do the same thing. Fortunately, CVErr(xlErrNull) works.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest I can get is to set the return value to be a Variant and return null:

```
Function Blah() As Variant
    Blah = Null

End Function

Sub Test()
    Range("A1").Value = Blah()
End Sub
```

I would advise against this though, personally; it is very unusual and may cause problems further down the line.

Comment: I'm calling the function from a cell - perhaps the result is different to when the value is set in the way your code shows. When you're calling the function from a cell, and the function returns Null, the cell will display 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should return an error, like this:

```
Function retError()
    ' This function returns an error. 
    retError = CVErr(vbValue)
End Function
```

In a cell, it would display as `#VALUE!`, which has the benefit of propagating through formulae in spreadsheet (make sure user knows there's an error), while it doesn't get counted by some functions like `COUNT`. Note that `COUNTA` still counts those cells.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  So what I did was create a dummy variable and set it equal to the function..

The function I had took some variables and then displayed them in a message box and I didn't want to return any values so I did this:

x = myfunction(a,b)

It worked perfectly.