# Excel - Ignore blank cells in validation list

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2013

Ok so I have two columns in one worksheet.

My 3rd worksheet tab has this:

In column B:
Original Performance NorGrip
Gold Blank Disc
Gold Blank Disc
Truckbed Liner Kit

In column C:
Grade
Grade
Dimensions

However, I want a list that shows this:
Original Performance NorGrip
Gold Blank Disc Grade
Gold Blank Disc Dimensions

And since Truckbed Liner Kit has a blank column to the right, I would rather it not even appear in the list.
So this is what I have:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",CONCATENATE(B2," - ",C2))
```

In a random column on that worksheet tab. So I then create a named range group called ProductGroupAttributes

And then in worksheet tab 4, I have a data validation list `=ProductGroupAttributes`

However, it puts all the blank columns in since my first formula inserts `""` where blank... so it doesn't truly ignore the blank columns. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using formulas.  You'll need to use VBA.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel).