# Excel Chart Bug when using =NA()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

This is really bugging me now.

There seems to be an issue in chart plotting where the "=NA" formula is ignored when it appears between two groups of data points.

The following plotted as a line graph should produce two identical lines but one at 0.5 and one at 1.0.

For some reason line A does not show a gap when x = 10 to 13

Is this a bug? I really need case A to work, or i need a workaround. Can anyone suggest something?

Win7 Excel 2007

[image]
[image]

Comment: as far as there is an empty B13 cell you will not get the same results. What about this cell??

Comment: @KazJaw The results should be the same. An empty cell and a cell =NA() should both be treated as nonvisible data points in a chart. For some reason using the empty cell to break up the groups in "B" allows the data to be correctly displayed.

Comment: NA is not the same as empty or zero even if one could expect it. [THIS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/na-HP005209188.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) could clarify it a bit.

Comment: @kazjaw Im not saying that empty and zero are the same.

Comment: @KazJaw if A = [1,=NA(),1,=NA(),1,=NA(),1] then only 3 data point should be visible when plotted. In practice the "=NA" are plotted. This is inconsitent behaviour because i.e. A = [1,1,1,=NA(),=NA(),=NA()] only shows 3 data points.

Comment: it is inconsistent and it isn't, it depends on point of view. How I solved such situation? by implementing `=IF()` function in data area. If not possible- I implemented such a solution to new area close to the original data and I created chart based on new area. That's all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a filter to select all data points that should be hidden and then deleting the contents of the cell works.

As I have lots of charts to do this to I was able to implement the "filter and delete" process using .Autofilter and .ClearContents methods.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is due to the way Excel is handling "Empty" cells. It appears there isn't a way to return a properly empty cell, but different workarounds have been discussed previously:

[Return empty cell from formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel)

Comment: That is correct, a formula cannot return an empty cell. For chart plotting purposes, setting a cell formula to =NA() should allow that cell to be ignored when plotting, as if it were an empty cell. Clearly in line A this is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an XY chart than the "blank" added with `=NA()` will not cause a blank in the line. Try adding labels and see what happens.

Also, see [Jon Peltier's](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/mind-the-gap-charting-empty-cells/) blog post titled 'Mind the Gap' for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is saying "I wish `#N/A` left a gap in a chart". I wish it, or something, would. But if wishes were horses, then beggars would ride.

Microsoft has yet to provide a way for a worksheet formula to be treated as a blank. A null string (`""`) looks blank, but isn't. `#N/A` looks ugly, and isn't treated as a blank, but to certain charts, it's almost as good.

`#N/A` causes a line or scatter plot not to draw a marker, but it has no effect on the line connecting points, so the line connects the points on either side of the `#N/A`.

I've written a few tutorials about blanks and gaps, maybe something here will help:
[Mind the Gap](http://peltiertech.com/mind-the-gap-charting-empty-cells/)
[VBA Approaches to Plotting Gaps in Excel Charts](http://peltiertech.com/vba-approaches-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/)
[Another approach to plotting gaps in Excel charts](http://peltiertech.com/another-approach-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/)

**Edit - Commentary**

I would say that the behavior I've described is not a bug in the way charts handle `#N/A`. The fact that there is no way to get a formula to make a cell behave as a blank cell is the problem, and it's a significant oversight by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a NA data when dealing with line chart do:

- select your chart
- right click
- select "Select Data"
- click on "Hidden and empty cells"
- unselect "Connect data points with line"