# Imported number format is in scientific, need general number

Tags: excel

I need to convert the column in excel to Number(Integer) datatype from General in Excel document.

I get data from external system which is displayed as "1E+14" and needs to change it to "100000000486422".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers are correctly exported from the 'external system' then your column widths and/or number format are insufficient for Excel to *display* the number correctly. Widen the column widths to accommodate the 15 digits and use a cell number format of the *Number* type or custom number format of *0*.

Note that Excel has a 15 digit floating point precision limit and will 'round' 16 digits to what it perceives as the 15 most important. Example: 100000000486422*9* becomes 1000000004864220.

See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113) for more info.

**EDIT:**

As per the comments, I would recommend using bulk operations instead of looping through cells for individual changes.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Columns("AI:AI").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
            .Cells.NumberFormat = "0"
        End With
        .Columns("AI:AI").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

That *should* resolve any time delay (aka *looping*) issues you experience but there may be larger underlying problems. Post back with a more complete scope of any problems you continue to experience.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim countRows As Long
     Set Rng = Range("AI1:AI65536" &        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    For x = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count Step 1
    Rng.Cells(x, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
    Next x
    End With
    End Sub

Comment: I am using above script for my requirement and its fulfilled my requirement but problem is it gets run for entire column. what if i have to run it for only rows which have data populated in it?

Comment: @Sourabh - Check to see if Excel thinks the cells are truly blank. Use Ctrl+↑ to see if the active cell actually stops on a cell that looks blank. If it does not, you need to use Data ► Text-to-Columns ► Fixed Width ► Finish on each of the cells to make those cells truly blank. see [Zero Length String Microsoft Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830884/zero-length-string-microsoft-access#25848174)