# Returning Empty from user defined function returns actually 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string, vba

I need to fill a cell with the result of a user function. If the result of the function is different from zero, the cell should be simply filled with the result of the function; so far so good.

But if the result is zero I want the cell to be empty.

So I wrote this user defined function:

```
Function MyTestFunction(n As Integer) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer

    result = n * 2

    If result = 0 Then
        MyTestFunction = Empty
    Else
        MyTestFunction = result
    End If
End Function
```

The function has no real purpose, it's just for investigating this issue.

The Excel sheet is like follows:

[image]

Cells A1 to A3 is just typed in data, cells B1 to B3 contain:

- B1:  `=MyTestFunction(A1)`
- B2:  `=MyTestFunction(A2)`
- B3:  `=MyTestFunction(A3)`

Now why does cell B3 display `0` instead of being empty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your function so as to always return an integer and so it does. An empty value is not an integer. You can modify your function as follows:

```
Function MyTestFunction(n As Integer) As Variant
    Dim result As Integer

    result = n * 2

    If result = 0 Then
        MyTestFunction = ""
    Else
        MyTestFunction = result
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That works, but unfortunately the empty cell returned like this cannot be used in certain formulas. For example if I put the formula `=B2+B3` into cell B4, I get an error instead of 4 (4+0). On the other hand `=SUM(B1:B3)` works.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - Your example shows that the best substitute for an *Empty* depends on the intended use for the result, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27198611/2707864).

Comment: @Michael Walz - As sancho.s correctly points out, you cannot really return an 'empty' value. The modified version of the function that I suggested returns an empty string if the result is 0. This makes the cell appear empty when in fact it contains a string. So when you try to add an integer to a string (`=B2+B3`) you get the error. When you sum a range (`=SUM(B1:B3)`) the cell(s) containing the string is ignored so the addition is successful. A work-around for this issue would be to use the IF function when adding cell values like so: `=IF(B2 = "",0,B2)+IF(B3 = "",0,B3)`.

Comment: @Zeno Thanks. I've come to the same conclusion. For addition I use now `SUM` and for substraction I write a user defined function `DIFF` that takes care of the required conversions.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot return an *Empty* from any formula (with either builtin or user defined functions)**, see [this](http://excel.tips.net/T002814_Returning_a_Blank_Value.html).

"" is not the same as *Empty*, and they behave differently in many cases. A manifestation of the difference can be obtained by executing in the immediate window the line below, on both a selected empty cell and a cell containing ""

```
? TypeName(Selection.Value)
```

The most useful substitute for *Empty* as the result of a formula depends on your use of the cell containing the formula, see [this](http://peltiertech.com/mind-the-gap-charting-empty-cells/) for a taste of it.

Still in the ToDo list of MS (or perhaps not...)

**EDIT**:
I found the following relevant question (it is worth checking the answers)

[Return empty cell from formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel)