# Leave a cell blank if condition is false

Tags: excel, if-statement, find, replaceall

Other questions have touched on this and offered solutions that are not viable for a very large data set. I have a formula like the following across 9 columns:

```
=IF(A1=A2, B2, "zz")
```

I then autofill about 3.5 million cells + copy -> paste values. Then I find and replace "zz" with "empty cell". However, finding and replacing a million or so "zz" strings is a very slow process. I'd rather not write anything there in the first place. So my question is, how to I write the following formula:

```
=IF(A1=A2, B2, 'leave cell alone and write nothing there at all')
```

Excel seems to be incapable of not touching a cell in case of FALSE (or TRUE for that matter).

Comment: Why not just `if(a1=a2,b2,'')`?

Comment: If you're really hung up on blank string vs empty cell, then I'd suggest writing a macro which simply skips writing to cells when your condition isn't met. If you turn off screen refreshing, its probably going to be a lot faster when processing 3.5M cells.

Comment: `=IF(A1=A2, B2, "")` is what you are looking for

Comment: Can you step back and explain why an empty string as in  `=IF(A1=A2, B2, "")`  will not work in your case?

Comment: Here you go! Get a true empty blank if condition is met: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351425/1903793

Answer (score 6):

The fact that the cell contains a formula already means that it is not truly empty. Common practice is to use an empty string, like

=IF(A1=A2, B2,"")

There are not many situations where this will be problematic, and if a problem arises, in most cases there are different techniques that can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Let NULL be the name of a cell that has "" in it, and BLANK be the name of a cell that is truly blank.

NULL is not truly blank; ISBLANK(NULL) will return FALSE.  But note that '=' takes blank and null cells to be identical.  So for any cell C1:

```
(C1="")
(C1=BLANK)
(C1=NULL)
```

will all return TRUE if C1 is truly blank OR if it contains "".  (I find this simpler than using COUNTBLANK(C1)>0, which has been suggested elsewhere.)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
=IF(A1=A2,B2,TRIM(""))
```

Comment: This doesn't work - excel still views it as something there