# Return blank cell only if referred cell is blank, but return aging if date is entered

Tags: excel, cell, formula, equation

I'm attempting an aging formula. I have one column with dates I've submitted info, but some rows in the column haven't been submitted. In another column I want to have an aging formula. If the "submitted date" cell is blank, I want the aging cell to be blank. If there is a date entered, I want it to show how many days it's been since it was submitted.

I'm pretty new to excel formulas. I know how to create the aging, and I know how to make one cell blank if another is blank. But I do not know how to combine both formulas into one cell.

Comment: Can you share more info? Exact formulas that you have? The output that you want? Screenshots/links?

Comment: The output that I want is as follows: If the "date submitted" cell is blank, I want it to return a blank cell. BUT if there is a date in the "date submitted" column, I want it to show me how many days it's been since I had submitted. The aging formula i'm using is "=BI1-AC2", where BI1 is todays date and AC2 is the "date submitted". The formula i'm using to return a blank cell if the "date submitted" cell is blank, is "=IF(ISBLANK(AC5),AC5,AF5)", there AC5 is the date submitted, and AF5 is the aging column cell.

Comment: Can you post a sample table, and a sample "finished" table? I think this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @pnuts - That's what I was thinking, the only potential problem is if DLaV uses that today, then opens the sheet tomorrow, the days will update (which may be what DLaV is looking for, but it's worth a note for OP).

Comment: I don't know how to add a table or screenshot or share the file. I've tried pasting into the comment box but it won't. It should be pretty straight forward (but i'm not sure how). I do want it to have the number of days change and update daily. above when you type is quotation marks in the formula, would i insert a cell?

Comment: Where he put quotation marks in the formula, you keep there.  If the cell `AC2` is blank, you will return a blank (the double quotes is "blank"). Put the formula exactly as he has it in the grey.  FYI to add a screenshot, you can take a screenshot, upload to www.imgur.com and post a link to the URL here (until you get enough rep. to add in the question itself).

Comment: IT WORKED...Thank you for your time! I've never posted to a forum like this before and you guys helped so much. In terms of understanding what I've done to do it in the future, i'm not sure if I'd be able to combine these types of formulas again, but my spreadsheet is good to go now. Thanks again....

Comment: If you want to get true blank, not just double quote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351425/1903793

Answer (score 0):

Please 'try' :)

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AC2),"",TODAY()-AC2)
```

[TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-5eb3078d-a82c-4736-8930-2f51a028fdd9) is a function that automatically updates according to your system clock. To have choice about what the formula deems as the reference point, change `TODAY()` to a cell reference where a specific date is entered (and where it can be changed to suit).

`""` is not quite a true 'blank' but the display is of nothing, so for most purposes 'good enough'.