# Excel - How to leave cell blank instead of 0?

Tags: excel, cell, zero, emptydatatext

I'm not using a numerical formula. All I have is a simple reference to another cell.

```
=(Sheet1!D8)
```

If that cell is blank, I want to have the cell on this page blank too, **not** a 0. How do I do that? I want it to appear empty to anyone, not just me, so I don't think simply editing excel settings would work? None of my google search results, including MS office site, have been helpful.

Comment: Get true empty cell as a formula result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39351425/1903793

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!D8),"",Sheet1!D8)
```

You can force a formula to evaluate as text instead of as a number by adding '& ""' to the end like below, but if you are dealing with numbers this isn't great.

```
=(Sheet1!D8)&""
```

See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/515932/display-blank-when-referencing-blank-cell-in-excel-2010) for other ideas.