# UDF returning zero when executing rng.value=""

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

Vba excel 2013 returning zero when executing rng.value=""

```
Function Delete_UDF(rng)
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Volatile
    rng.Value = ""
End Function
```

This is returning zero, anyone knows why?

Comment: This looks more like a **Sub** than a **Function**. But whatever it is, you need to learn the most basic of basics of VBA if you can't get this right.

Answer (score 3):

Your function does not return anything. You need to add something like:

```
Delete_UDF = "return value"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of Application.Volatile tells me you are using this UDF on a worksheet and this will **never** work from the worksheet.

A UDF called from the worksheet cannot change any cell on that worksheet or other worksheet other than returning a value to the cell it is being used on. If you used this in A1 like `=Delete_UDF(A1)` it would be a circular reference and not work for that reason.

This will **never** work as a UDF on the worksheet.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel/1119661#1119661