# How to use ISBLANK while allowing multiple iterations

Tags: google-sheets, iteration

I want this cell to show "N" if it's empty. But obviously I'm then running into the problem that it's no longer blank if it's got code in it.
I turned off the limit on iterative calculations, but that didn't help me because instead of getting a circularity error, I just get a Y in every column, because isblank=false is always the case by virtue of me putting the code there.

Is the only way to fix this to create a new column so I can turn off multiple iterations? If that's the only way I can't really use that, since then I'd have to create a sister column for every column in the spreadsheet which is just too much.

```
=IF(isblank(H51)=false, "Y", "N")
```

Comment: Are you trying to put your formula in the cell it is referencing? If yes, that won't work.

Comment: By definition, if your target cell contains a formula, it will not be blank.  You could consider using color (via conditional formatting), or else you will need a VBA macro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return empty cell from formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119614/11683)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return empty cell from formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel)

Comment: You may want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58697587/edit) to explain what it is you are trying to accomplish.