# Excel VBA to generate #N/A error on sheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a sheet formula of `IF(Test1>0, Test1, NA())` which is designed to put a 'controlled' #N/A in the sheet if the condition is not met.  Similarly, I am using `IFERROR(Test2,NA())` elsewhere in the same sheet.

As the formulae for Test*n* are long, I would like to put them into a UDF but can't find a way to generate a 'controlled' #N/A error (one not green-flagged as an error on the sheet).

So far I have got as far as:

```
Function GTZero(sngInput As Single) As Variant

    If sngInput > 0 Then GTZero = sngInput Else GTZero = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function
```

This is then called in the sheet as `=GTZero(Test1)`. The answer *looks* right but Excel flags this as a true error.  I don't want to just use "#N/A" text as I need to use the results in a chart and want to skip the #N/As

Comment: You can't, as far as I know. *Any* function that returns `#N/A` other than `NA()` will be flagged if you have that error checking option switched on.

Comment: Why don't you use `=IFERROR(GTZero(Test1),NA())`? If what you are trying to do is to calculate `Test1` just once, this should work for you.

Comment: Instead of returning `#N/A`, return a "BLANK CELL" as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel). When I say "BLANK CELL", I do not mean `""` as this will get plotted in the chart. Also Right click on the `Chart | Select Data | Hidden and Empty Cells | Show Empty Cell as "Connect data points with line"`This again is tested on a line chart.

Comment: BTW I am referring to `Przemyslaw Remin` answer in the above link

Comment: My original assumption was that "Test1" was a named range. However, the statement "As the formulae for Test*n* are long" gives me some doubt. How is `Test1` really represented when you call the function? Because otherwise your code seems fine.

Comment: BTW, I just tested your code as written in Excel O365, and it worked as expected. And yes, it is a 'true error' because that is what you are telling the UDF to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is not possible. I've tried putting `=NA()` or just `#N/A` as string in one cell and returning a reference to that cell from the UDF. I've also tried defining a name which refers to `=NA()` and returning this name, but nothing worked. 

According to [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-GB/Article/detect-errors-in-formulas-3a8acca5-1d61-4702-80e0-99a36a2822c1):

> Note: If you enter an error value directly in a cell, it is stored as that error value but is not marked as an error. However, if a formula in another cell refers to that cell, the formula returns the error value from that cell.

Comment: Looks like you're right.  I think probably your suggestion of just `=IFERROR(GTZero(Test1),NA())` is going to be the way to go.  Either that or live with / 'ignore the flags.

Answer (score 1):

No VBA needed. You can do this trick using formulas:

*e^(ln(whatever))* always returns *whatever* because *e^* and *ln()* are inverse functions.

Except... *ln()* has no real solution for negative numbers and 0, resulting in error in Excel, which is what you want.

So you can do this:

```
= IFERROR(EXP(LN(Test1)),NA())
```

Same as your formula, except `Test1` only appears once.

See below working example. Formula in `B1` is dragged down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImaginaryHuman.  That's a really elegant solution and I get it but I'd be a bit worried about someone coming along later and getting worried by the EXP and LN!

Comment: That seems like a silly reason to not do something... but ok. Anyway you should mark one of these answers as correct if they helped you.

Comment: A thought - could also use `=IFERROR(Test1^1,NA())` to give the same sort of result?

Comment: @ChemEnger No... (any number)^1 is always defined, even for negative numbers. This accomplishes nothing. Try it for yourself. (-1)^1 still returns (-1) in Excel.