How to clear the contents of each cell in a range if it matches the content of the cell directly above it

Is it possible without the use of VBA?
I have tried using this formula: =IF(H2=H3, "", H3) along the whole column but it is still displaying each date. I was expecting for the cell to be blank if the condition held or to display the date if it did not.

Try IF(INT(H2)=INT(H3),"",H3)

@BigBen doesn't work. The cells are formatted as dates and not numbers.

Format doesn't change the underlying value. Dates are just formatted numbers. The above formula also works with text-that-looks-like-a-date. If it's not working, then there's some detail missing from your question.

In what cell are you putting the formula?

Have you tried making the FALSE argument to H2, also what it seems from the screenshot, those are true dates as in Excel Dates are by default right aligned (changes to left when hit CTRL  ~) or  aligned unless you have made any changes by formatting the alignment.

I am putting the formula: =IF(INT(H2)=INT(H3)," ",H3) in cell H2 and it applies to $H$2:$H$958

Try putting it in a different column

@MayukhBhattacharya do you mean this: =IF(INT(H2)=INT(H3), FALSE, H3)? Although, looking at the comments under this thread I don't think there is a way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel?rq=2

"Applies to:"?  Are you trying to do conditional formatting? Otherwise it sounds like you are trying to affect a cell in which you put the formula and this cannot be done with formula and will require vba.

Using the formula cell as reference cell is circular referencing. You need to either use a different column to show values how you want them to, or switch to vba

No, I was referring to this: =IF(H2=H3, "", H2)

Not sure whether this is what you want:


Create new conditional formatting, Classic > Use a Formula
Apply number format ;;;
Selecting the range starting from the second cell

